# Always show scrollbar when a html table is scrollable

Tags: html, css

I have html for table inside a div.
The div is set with overflow:auto and a max-height, so that if the number of rows exceed the max-height the table become scrollable.

However the scrollbar appears only when I start to scroll...

What I'd like to achieve is: always showing the scrollbar when the table is scrollable, not showing the scrollbar at all if the table is smaller than the div max-height (table it's not scrollable)

Thanks

Comment: Certain OS or browser's settings show the native scroll bar only when it's moving. However using `overflow:scroll` will always show the scroll bar.

Comment: You mean even when the table is not scrollable?

Comment: I'm mean: even if the table do not contain enough rows to exceed the div height, yes.

Comment: So what I've asked is not possible?

Comment: Not with CSS and the original browser scroll bar. Are you testing this on a Mac ?